# Can Cauchy's integral formula be used on the boundary point?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Can Cauchy's integral formula be used if the point a is on the boundary of the circle ? The theorem is given below.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The boundary of the circle is $\gamma$, and if $a\in\gamma$, then the integrand doesn't exist at $a$.

If you need to work with an $a$ on the boundary of $D$, then enlarge $D$ a little. You can do that because $\overline{D}\subset U$.

Comment: According to you integration over |z|=1 , dz/z^2-1 does not exist .Is not it?

Comment: I didn’t say the integral doesn’t exist. I said the integrand is undefined at a point on the path of integration. That means the path integral must be regarded as an improper integral. You can’t apply Cauchy directly here.